# Let $A,B,C,D$ lie on a circle, $AD$ and $BC$ meet at $E$. The circle through $A,C,E$ have centre $O$. Prove that $BD$ is perpendicular to $EO$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let A,B,C,D lie on a circle, where AD and BC meet at E. Let the circle through A,C,E have centre O. Prove that BD is perpendicular to EO.

I saw this question posted earlier but it was put on hold and now I can't find it anymore... I thought I'd repost with my solution. Not sure about the rules on that; Let me know if I have to take it down.

Are there any other ways to prove this? There was an answer to the old post regarding defining a circle through B,E,G, with BE as the diameter, and by Thales theorem this would prove that the angle at G is 90 degrees. But how can you prove that BE would be the diameter of the circle through B,E,G without assuming angleBGE to be 90 degrees?

[image]

Picture by someone who answered the original post

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Reim's theorem:

https://mathsolympian.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/reims-theorem/

Then by Reim we have that tangent $EE$ on circle $ACE$ is parallel to $DB$. But since tangent $EE$ is perpendicular to radius $EO$ we are done.

Comment: +1. That's essentially the solution I was about to post. :) Reim's Theorem itself may a *bit* much, though, since making reference to it, and then explaining how it applies here, takes about as much effort as "in-lining" its one-line proof into the current situation. Something like: "Let $\overline{EF}$ be tangent to $\bigcirc O$, then *these three angles* are congruent, so that $\overline{BD}\parallel\overline{EF}\perp\overline{OE}$, and we are done!" (My answer would've made this a self-evident picture-proof.) That said, Reim's is a neat general result worth knowing. Thanks for showing it!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

I used circle theorems (which I just realised I forgot to name exactly).

Comment: Posting a picture of text is discouraged, since (1) it's hard to read, and (2) it's impossible to search. Now's a good time for you to learn MathJax, the way of writing mathematical notation here (and elsewhere). [Here's a tutorial.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Make your best attempt, and someone can help you fix any problems.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a go and edit in a couple of days @Blue